# Submitting thesis without supervisors' reviews

Tags: phd, thesis, thesis-committee, defense

I am a Ph.D. student, about to finish my thesis draft. My case is a bit special as I didn't receive any guidance from my supervisors. It is very unlikely that they know details about my work, results or even what I propose in my research. 
I have submitted three journal papers but I will receive reviews, not before my thesis submission. As, I don't have the official approval of my results, so I have second thoughts about my work. Although, I have worked hard enough and was honest in my research.

I request the suggestions about how can I proceed? Is it ok to submit my thesis to reviewers/reporters without my supervisor's reviews?

Thank you a million in advance

Comment: Even if they know nothing about your research, or your research area, presumably they do know what a well-written PhD thesis looks like, and will be able to provide you guidance on how to improve your thesis.

Comment: Just reading this makes me a bit sad. How do you go 4+ years on a PhD without discussing any aspects of your research work with your supervisors?

Comment: Is there anyone who was in contact with your work/results/you in any scientific manner during your time as a PhD student? Are you sure you don't need some kind of approval of you supervisors to be able to submit?

Comment: Vote to close as off-topic because whether the OP can submit his thesis without supervisor's review is up to his school. We have no way to know the answer. Maybe the school would allow it, maybe not. (Although my guess is no, what if the student submits thesis containing only garbage?)

Comment: @scaaahu: *what if the student submits thesis containing only garbage?* – then they will fail. When I submitted my thesis, no involvement of my supervisor was required in the official process. Of course, not talking to your supervisor is still inadvisable.

Comment: Is there any communication between you and your supervisors? Have you tried to inform them that you intend to submit your thesis? If yes, how did they react?

Comment: I am from France, here in the administration, there is no way to keep track of supervisors and their involvement in the thesis. I can do it!

Answer (score 2):

That depends, first of all, on the PhD regulations of your department or your university. The conditions that have to be satisfied in order to submit a thesis vary from one institution to the other.

Answer (score 2):

As Uwe said, much depends on the exact protocols at your university. But even if it is technically possible, the supervisor will likely be present on the defense, will be able to influence your score and probably has a rather good contact with at least some members of the jury and/or the responsible committees as well. And it's not a good thing when the jury finds out you didn't consult your supervisor prior to handing your document in, unless there is a very good reason for that.

Now this doesn't mean your supervisor has to review it before you send it in (although he/she would be stupid not to...). You can politely ask your supervisor if its OK you hand in the PhD without waiting for his review. But sending in your PhD without your supervisor being aware of that, is a very bad idea, even if your supervisor didn't make any other contribution to your work.

Comment: I don't find any such formal requirement in [these PhD regulations](http://www.cs.uni-saarland.de/fileadmin/content/Downloads/Education/Ph.D._Graduate_School/Regulations/PO_Natwiss-Techn-Fakultaeten_Nov_2013_-_EN_-_Halbformat.pdf). You need a declaration of consent of some faculty member who agrees to supervise your thesis in order to be admitted as a doctoral student; but in principle you might submit your thesis without your supervisor's consent (even though that's usually unwise).

Comment: @Uwe You're right, updated accordingly. I checked again, and also at my university that is technically possible.

Comment: I am wise enough to ask my supervisors. But unfortunately, I met some assholes who don't seem to care. My collaborative lab from Spain has helped me a lot.  I have followed the protocol, I kept proof of all the email records which are sufficient to prove that they don't want to do their job. Nevertheless, I can not jeopardize my career, so I kept working, publishing papers (without their help although their names are on it). I have thesis corrections from the lab from Spain. I don't want to get stuck just because my profs didn't do their job. I did mine and honestly.

Comment: @TejaswineeDarure I feel your pain, and I'm sorry you have to go through that. If you notified your supervisor you are going to hand in and he/she didn't react, just hand it in so you can take the next step in your carreer. I wish you all the best.